# PHP/MySQL script won't let user visit more than once in an alotted time

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a script for a game I'm working on that only rewards a user's click on a specific link once each day.

I'm thinking the best way would be to make a field in the reward table for user history which logs the username and time that they got their reward.

So every time the link is clicked, these values need to be stored in the field "history" along with all the others from the last 24 hours:

```
$username = GET['username'];
$time = time();
```

What would the best way be to go about storing multiple values within the one field, multiple dimensional arrays? How would I store them and later retrieve them?

After I figure out how to retrieve the values form the array I was thinking that using preg_match() to find duplicates of the username. If that returned true, then check time();, if that is older than 24 hours, update time(); to current and reward, else if it is not older than 24 hours no new reward, if false, then they get a reward.

Any ideas?

EDIT: Alright, then if putting the values into one field is not the best way what is? There are many rewards added every day (100's), and they expire rather quickly, so making a field for every reward within the table of user_info would surely not be the best way would it? That would mean every time a new reward is added, that a new field would have to be inserted into the user_info table... Then when a reward expires all those columns would have to be deleted. Is this what you guys are suggesting?

Comment: DO NOT STORE MULTIPLE VALUES IN A SINGLE DB COLUMN.... normalize your database if you need to store multiple history entries against a user's rewards

Answer (score 0):

Why all that business with multi-dimensional arrays and regexes? You have MySQL, ***use it***!

Store a row per reward

```
| user_id | last_rewarded_at |
|   42    |     2011-01-11   |
```

This way you can trivially add new rewards, check if a user was rewarded on a given day, etc.

Comment: @user1142872: you have to have a ROW per reward, not a COLUMN. And store them in separate table to not affect users table.

Comment: @Mob: that's because he didn't understand it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I guess  just can't explain the question properly, because none of these answers are helping 1 bit.

Comment: @user1142872: either that, or you want to do something *so* bizarre that we can't comprehend it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to "What would the best way be to go about storing multiple values within the one field" is DO NOT DO IT.

One field - one value, it's as easy as that.

Answer (score 0):

If you REALLY feel the need to ignore these answers and STILL store all the data in one field (poor practice) - then use json to store multi-dimensional data in one field, using json_encode to store it and json_decode to read it as an object

```
<?php
$stored = json_encode($array_data);

$read = json_decode($stored);
?>
```

Bear in mind that json encoded data will be decoded into an OBJECT not an ARRAY, to get an ARRAY use:

```
$read = (array) json_decode($stored);
```

You will suffer performance issues doing things this way